# Permissions not being displayed when logging in with Facebook using Ionic

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I am developing an application which uses login with facebook and I need to fetch the user detials to use them in my application.
I am using the following code to get the access token.

```
 window.facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends","user_gender","user_age_range"], function (success) {
       // Some code

      }, function (error) {
        logfacebook("error in connected method after singed in" + JSON.stringify(error));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
```

This is what I am able to see:

[image: Facebook image]

I am able to see name, profile picture, Friends list and email address. Even though I have added age and gender in the array. What am I doing wrong? I have some where I need to add permission list in the developer console. I tried to find it but I am not able to find where do I need to add the permissions.

Comment: Are you testing this with an account that has a role in the app? Otherwise, you of course need to get your app’s use of those permissions reviewed, before you can ask normal users for them.

Comment: Yes I am testing with an account that has admin role in the app.

Comment: What API version is your app using?

Comment: I dont know what api version I am using. I know I am using this plugin cordova-plugin-facebook4 which is 1.9.1.